# In VBA, How can I trim any characters not just whitespaces?

Tags: vba

Due to some other sloppy coding, I need to remove leading or trailing vbCrLf or reduce any instances of more than one consecutive vbCrLf to a single line.

So how can I execute the trim function, but to trim a character other than " " ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are functions to do just that

```
Function TrimAny(ByVal myString As String, myTrim As String) As String
    If myString = "" Or myTrim = "" Then TrimAny = myString: Exit Function
    While inStB(myString, myTrim & myTrim): myString = Replace(myString, myTrim & myTrim, myTrim): Wend
    myString = TrimStart(myString, myTrim)
    myString = TrimEnd(myString, myTrim)
    TrimAny = myString
End Function

Function TrimEnd(ByVal myString As String, myTrim As String) As String
    If myString = "" Or myTrim = "" Then TrimEnd = myString: Exit Function
    While Right(myString, Len(myTrim)) = myTrim: myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - Len(myTrim)): Wend
    TrimEnd = myString
End Function

Function TrimStart(ByVal myString As String, myTrim As String) As String
    If myString = "" Or myTrim = "" Then TrimStart = myString: Exit Function
    While Left(myString, Len(myTrim)) = myTrim: myString = Right(myString, Len(myString) - Len(myTrim)): Wend
    TrimStart = myString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `RegExp`:

```vb
Function CrLfTrim(ByVal text As String) As String
    ' set a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5' in Tools->References VBE menu
    Static re As RegExp ' re is Static and stores the object between function calls, so there is no need to create it each time
    If re Is Nothing Then   ' it is only necessary to create re if it is Nothing (first time)
        Set re = New RegExp
        re.Global = True
    End If
    With re
        .Pattern = "(^(\x0D\x0A)+)|((\x0D\x0A)+$)" 'set pattern to remove leading and trailing vbCrLf
        text = .Replace(text, "")   'remove leading and trailing vbCrLf
        .Pattern = "(\x0D\x0A){2,}" 'set the pattern for the internal sequential vbCrLf
        CrLfTrim = .Replace(text, vbCrLf) ' replace the internal sequential vbCrLf with one vbCrLf
    End With
End Function
```

Usage example:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim txt As String: txt = vbCrLf & "Lorem ipsum dolor sit " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "amet, consectetur " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Debug.Print "Before: [" & txt & "]"
    Debug.Print "After: [" & CrLfTrim(txt) & "]"
End Sub
```

Prints:

```
Before: [
Lorem ipsum dolor sit 


amet, consectetur 

]
After: [Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consectetur ]
```